# How to use an external program (Gnuplot) with Lualatex and Texmaker?

Tags: luatex, texmaker, gnuplot

I do not have too much experience with LaTeX and I would like to configure Texmaker so that LuaLaTeX can use an external program.

In this case, I would like to reproduce a graph (using Gnuplot (which has been added to my path envrironment variable : [image])) from the documentation of PGFplots:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view={0}{90}]
        \addplot3[domain=-2:2, domain y=-1.3:1.3, contour gnuplot={number=14}] 
            {exp(-x^2-y^2)*x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I got the error message:

```
! Package pgfplots Error: sorry, plot file{"Test"_contourtmp0.table} could not be opened.
```

After some research on the internet, it seems that LuaLaTeX cannot by default use external programs. So I tried to configure TeXmaker to make this possible, but I don't think there is such an option, and the TeXmaker manual doesn't tell me more...

Is it possible to do this with Texmaker?

*Note: I don't know if it matters, but I use the Miktex distribution.*

**Update**

On the advice of Gigiair, I have changed the default command of Texmaker.
[image]

Comment: You just have to add -enable-write18 to the lualatex command : "lualatex -interaction=nonstopmode  -enable-write18 %.tex" in the option tab

Comment: In LuaLaTeX you may need to add `\usepackage{shellesc}` in your preamble.

Comment: @JairoA.delRio It still doesn’t work. `:/` I have no idea why...

Answer (score 0):

Of course, TeXmaker invokes external programs, since `latex`, `lualatex`, `xelatex` are external programs to compile your source code.
But to use `gnuplot`, the compiler has to call external programs. It needs to be authorized to do so. To do so, add '-enable-write18' to the compiling command. It should look like this: `"lualatex -interaction=nonstopmode -enable-write18  %.tex"`

Comment: I did what you told me to do, but I keep getting the same error message. `:/` Is there anything else I need to do? I deleted my auxiliary files before recompiling and I use LuaLaTeX for compiling instead of _Quick Build_.

Comment: Is gnuplot installed on your box? Make sure that the 'gnuplot' command is recognized by your installation by typing 'gnuplot' in a command interpreter.

Comment: I use sometimes Gnuplot as a standalone, and have never had any problems. So it seems to me that Gnuplot is well installed on my computer. And Gnuplot  has been added to the path envrironment variable during its installation.

Comment: I checked on a W10 installation. Your code compile fine. I have installed the mingw version which provide a gnuplot.exe file. I only changed the PATH to include  the path to gnuplot.exe.Did your really check in a command interpreter (eg CMD, powershell..) that 'gnuplot' is recognized as a Windows command ?
If so, I can't do more. For a standalone use, it can be called wgnuplot.exe.

Comment: This is what I have when I write "gnuplot" in Windows PowerShell : `G N U P L O T
        Version 5.2 patchlevel 8    last modified 2019-12-01

        Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2019
        Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

        gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
        faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"
        immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')

Terminal type is now 'wxt'
Encoding set to 'cp1252'.` Is that what you’re talking about?

Comment: it should compile. .
I would try to compile directly from a command line: "lualatex --enable-write18 Test". I'm not sure if it takes a dash or two before "enable". I am not a MikTeX user.